# How do I get the result from this async function?

Tags: javascript

### Problem

I'm trying to get the `diskName` value back from `this.getDiskName('C:')`
 and assign it to `element['name']`:

```
getDisksInfo () { 
  ...
  element['name'] = this.getDiskName('C:')
  ...
},

getDiskName (diskLetter) {
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec
    var cmd = `wmic logicaldisk where caption="${diskLetter}" get VolumeName`

    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      let diskName = stdout.split('\n')[1]
      return diskName
    })
  }
}
```

I tried doing this, but I keep getting different errors:

```
getDiskName (diskLetter, callback) {
    ...
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if callback(null, () => {
        let diskName = stdout.split('\n')[1]
        return diskName
      })
    ...
}
```

### Question

Could someone please explain how to return the value properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @CodeF0x I couldn't adapt other answers to this code. I always get an error saying callback is not defined. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: You can't return it.  Instead of `return diskName`, you need to set the value right there.  I'll create an answer with a more idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: well did you pass it a callback so it is defined?

Comment: @epascarello yes, but I don't know how to do it properly, I edited the code, could you please take a look?

Comment: Child process docs show how you can `promisify`  the `exec()` method

Comment: Using asynchronous functions is a new way of thinking for many.  Instead of returning a value and then just using it, you typically write a "callback" function that does what you want done with the value and then cause that function to be invoked with the value when the async function completes. In JS this often takes the form of a promise and the "then" function thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing either a callback coming into `getDiskName()` or a `Promise()` coming out.

Since the `Promise` approach seems to be more popular nowadays, I'll go with that for this answer.

With a `Promise` approach, you need the function to return a `Promise`. In most cases, you just wrap all the code up in a `Promise` and return that:

```
getDiskName(diskLetter) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // rest of your code in the function
    });
}
```

Then, instead of your `return`, you'll call `resolve()`:

```
let diskName = stdout.split('\n')[1];
resolve(diskName)
```

And for your error, you'll call reject:

```
if (err) {
  reject(err);
}
```

Then, in the function that uses it, you'll have to wait for the `then()` in your function:

```
this.getDiskName('C:').then(diskName => console.log(diskName))
```

The callback method is similar, you just pass in the callback into `getDiskName` and call it when you're ready.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I understand it now. I also wanted to use a promise for this, but I couldn't understand how they work, now it's clearer to me

Answer (score 1):

This is a more idiomatic method to handle a case like this.  We'll pass a function in to `getDiskName` which takes the disk name (which is the return value) as a parameter.

```
getDisksInfo () { 
  ...
  this.getDiskName('C:', function(diskName) {
    element['name'] = diskName;
  });
  // Note that code from here to the end doesn't have access
  // to element['name']
  ...
},

getDiskName (diskLetter, func) {
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec
    var cmd = `wmic logicaldisk where caption="${diskLetter}" get VolumeName`

    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      let diskName = stdout.split('\n')[1]
      func(diskName);
    })
  }
}
```

Now, this still might not work for you since perhaps you have code after the call which relies on knowing the diskName.  In that case, you would probably roll that code into your anonymous function.  Perhaps `getDisksInfo` takes a function as a parameter instead.

This is the general pattern, you have to determine how it best fits in your program.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it and it works as expected!